# Is there a certain depth which can be set with find_elements in selenium?

Tags: python, html, selenium, selenium-webdriver, element

Is it possible to restrict the depth of find_elements in selenium python. For example

```
element = driver.find_elements_by_tag_name(„li“)

# This is what would be saved
<ul>
<li>
  #smth
  <ul>
  <li>…</li>
  <li>…</li>
  </ul>
</li>

<li>
  #smth
  <ul>
  <li>…</li>
  <li>…</li>
  </ul>
</li>

</ul>
```

Here *element* would include the outer list, but also the inner lists (list within list).

Is it possible to only get the outer < li >?

Comment: Did you try the suggestion?

Comment: No, while waiting for an answer i went to bed and the next day i found a better way how to solve my problem, so I didn‘t try it.

Comment: would you guys care to share with the class?

Answer (score 0):

`driver.find_element_by_css_selector("li:first-of-type")` may solve your question.

Comment: Try this locator